# Get maximum value in a list within a list in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Here's my code:

```
public class Calculation
{
    public int Id;
    public string ErrorCode;
    public ICollection<CalculationDetails> CalculationDetails;
}

public class CalculationDetails
{
    public int Id;
    public decimal? Amount;
    public decimal? Rate;
    public string Category;
}

public static Category
{
    public const string CategoryA = "A";
    public const string CategoryB = "B";
}
```

I am having a list of calculations in the object `List<Calculation> calculations`.

**I want to fetch the maximum of Amounts of Category B from Calculations object.**

Comment: There is no `List<Calculation> calculations` in your sample code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should change your types to use immutable properties instead of exposed fields because it makes it difficult to reason about the state of an instance of `Calculation` and `CalculationDetails`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var calculations = new List<Calculation>(); //pretend it's filled

var maxAmountCategoryB = calculations
    .SelectMany(c => c.CalculationDetails)
    .Where(d => d.Category == Category.CategoryB)
    .Max(d => d.Amount.GetValueOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Calculation> calculations = ...

Decimal max = calculations
    .Where( c => c != null )
    .SelectMany( c => c.CalculationDetails )
    .Where( cd => cd != null )
    .Where( cd => cd.Category == Category.CategoryB )
    .Select( cd => cd.Amount ?? 0 )
    .DefaultIfEmpty( 0 )
    .Max();
```

Feel free to elide the `.Where( x => x != null )` if you're confident there are no nulls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var result = listOfCalculation.Max(x=>x.CalculationDetails
                                  .Where(c=>c.Category.Equals(Category.CategoryB))
                                  .Max(c=>c.Amount));
```

[Demo Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tJiD5Q)